# Why is Q → P a logical consequence of ¬(P → Q )

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, demorgans-law, fitch-proofs

I don't want to ask my professor about this because I'm awful at this and he's not the, uhh, *patient* type of professor to say the least.

ANYWAY, it was my understanding that `¬(P → Q )` and `(¬P → ¬Q )` mean two different things.
And that `Q → P` is equal to `(¬P → ¬Q )`.

Yet one of the answers to a question says that `Q → P` is a logical consequence of `¬(P → Q )`, which I just don't understand at all.

To confuse matters further, afaik `¬(p → q) ⟺ p ∧ ¬q` is correct, so I guess I'm just lost and missing something here in the definition of logical consequence?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might get better answers over at the [Computer Science StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) because StackOverflow is for questions about implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you're probably right this isn't the best place, I think actually the math stackexchange is best suited so I'll try that one once I can post again :)

Comment: `A` is a logical consequence of `B` if `B -> A` is always true. Go ahead and draw the truth table for `~(P -> Q) -> (Q -> P)`. You'll see that all entries come out as true. This of course is the "mechanical" explanation of it. If you're looking at it from a more linguistic perspective, think of when you can make `P` false while `Q` being true, given it isn't the case that `P -> Q`. You'll see that it never happens.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this does indeed make sense, I really was just getting confused by the linguistics it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps some more background - by logical consequence we usually mean the semantical notion of the entailment operator: the entailment A ⊨ B holds if B is true in all models in which A is true. In classical logic this is equivalent to saying that ⊨ A → B is true (i.e. the formula A → B is true in all models).

Let's have a look at the concrete consequence in question:

¬(P → Q) ⊨ Q → P

We only consider interpretations which make ¬(P → Q ) true. This is only the case if Q is false and P is true (making Q → P false and its negation true). But if Q is false, then Q → P is true because from a false premise follows everything.

Let's look if the two formulas are equivalent i.e. if also P → Q ⊨ ¬(P → Q):

Let's first go use the definition of implication and use de Morgan's rule to get:

P → Q ⊨ ¬¬P ∧ ¬Q

We can also remove the double negation that we end up with:

P → Q ⊨ P ∧ ¬Q

Now P → Q has three interpretations that make it true (P false + any value of Q and both P and Q true) but not even one makes P true and Q false (i.e. is a model of P ∧ ¬Q).  Therefore the formulas are not equivalent.